# Robot Navigation Within a Corridor

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to add a "virtual" corridor along the waypoints generated by the global planner (waypoints are in the middle of the virtual corridor), so the robot never leaves this "virtual" corridor when it's moving between the waypoints using a local planner. As an example, if during the robot's navigation within this corridor, an obstacle appears in front of the robot and covers the entire width of the corridor, the robot should stop.

I was wondering if I could do this by updating the costmap (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid), and marking all the cells outside the "virtual" corridor as obstacles at the beginning?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172984/robot-navigation-within-a-corridor/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct solution here is probably to modify the local planner, rather than trying to coerce the existing local planner to do what you've described. Here's why:

In the local planners, if the path is completely blocked they will abort and trigger a re-planning by the global planner. I suspect this isn't what you want.

By contrast, if you write your own local planner you can explicitly have it stay within a certain distance of the global plan, and have a configurable timeout for it to wait before triggering a re-planning when the path is completely blocked.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-06-06**:
Thanks. Yes, I don't want the robot to replan if the path is completely blocked. In the ROS Navigation Stack, the default local planner is implemented based on the Dynamic Window Approach. Is there a way to modify the DWA planner to keep the robot within a certain distance of the global plan?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-06**:
I haven't spent much time working with the DWA planner codebase, so I don't have any specific guidance to offer there.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-07**:
The rough way would be: Look for return false in the function that computes velocities and change it to only do so if some time has passed.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-06-07**:
Could you please elaborate? I didn't get how it helps to keep the robot within a certain distance of the global plan